# Could not decrypt (pad block corrupted) in Android (PBEWithMD5AndDES)

Tags: android, encryption, base64

Situation:

- String is getting encrypted in Java environment (javax.crypto.Cipher/PBEWithMD5AndDES), base64 encoded
- String is transfered to Android
- Same crypto decoder is used, only different base64 library

=> we could not decrypt, getting

> java.lang.SecurityException: Could not decrypt: pad block corrupted

During analysis we compared byte arrays, passed to the decode() method, in order to skip all possible base64 issues, and the arrays are identical.

Again, two identical byte arrays, passed to the same java module, produce different results (ok on java, exception on android).

Parameters, passed to Cipher module are hard-coded and identical on both platforms.

Where is the difference

Comment: Please provide the actual code you are using for encryption and decryption and a test vector which works on desktop Java but not Android.

Comment: Thanks for an offer. Looks like we have found the reason - different providers were used.

Answer (score 1):

We have finally found the difference between Java and Android code. It turned out Cipher component is just a container and does not implement anything by itself. The particular algorithm implementation is done by a provider and each platform has different list of providers configured. In our case if was some Sun implementation for Java and Bouncy Castle for Android. So it turned out that wir accidentaly used the encryption algorithm which implementation was different for different providers